# Photonic. vs Plasmonic

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I hear a lot about photonic and plasmonic structures being the future in many different applications, but what are the differences between them? Why would one want a material with both as opposed to just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photonic devices manipulate light to perform their function.For example, LEDs, lasers are photonic devices with their own set of physics and engineering applications.

Plasmonic devices manipulate [plasmons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon).

Plasmon is a quasi-particle that represents 1 quantum of plasma oscillation. An example of plasmons are collective oscillations of the free electron gas in a metal. Possible applications of plasmons include high frequency computer chips, high-resolution lithography. I am familiar with this as this in one of my research topics.